# HTML Scroll via menu

Tags: html

I have a menu that looks like below. I want to scroll between the items.

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Foods</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Drinks</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. On SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** within the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_scrollspy.asp). This might be a good starting point for you. It's about using bootstrap and jQuery.

Another solution is using HTML DOM `scrollIntoView` method:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #myDIV {
                height: 250px;
                width: 450px;
                overflow: auto;
                background: green;
            }
            #myDIVTwo {
                height: 250px;
                width: 450px;
                overflow: auto;
                background: blue;
            }
            #Food {
                margin:500px;
                height: 800px;
                width: 2000px;
                background-color: coral;
            }
            #Drinks {
                margin:500px;
                height: 800px;
                width: 2000px;
                background-color: red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <p>Click the button to scroll to the top of the element with id="content".</p>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#home" onclick="myFunction()">Food </a></li>
            <li><a href="#home" onclick="myFunctionTwo()">Drinks </a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="myDIV">
            <div id="Food">
                Some text inside an element. this is the food section 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="myDIVTwo">
            <div id="Drinks">
                Some text inside an element. this is the Drinks section 
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                var elmnt = document.getElementById("Food");
                elmnt.scrollIntoView();
            }
            function myFunctionTwo() {
                var elmntTwo = document.getElementById("Drinks");
                elmntTwo.scrollIntoView();
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Link only answers are not allowed on SO. Please delete this or form your own answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Sorry I was unaware I will edit, I wish simply trying to point the user in the right direction, I taught adding external links was ok, my misstake

Comment: but how can I add the function to a menu item?

Comment: @jacub I have edited the code to act as menu item like you posted above does this give you an idea

Comment: @JasonDelaney, thank you! I missed the "#" in the menu when I tried is the first time.

Comment: @jacub happy to help you if there is anything else just shout, be nice to accept the answer if the solution worked for you

Answer (score 0):

Use IDs of HTML elements to achieve this.

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#placeIWantToJump">Foods</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Drinks</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

...

<div id="placeIWantToJump"> ... </div>
```

Comment: I did try to do that, but I get the error message: the file could not be found

Comment: did you put the prefix # in the `href`? Look at the example carefully.

Answer (score 0):

In my caseit will be smooth scroll via menu. Try this ^_-:

```js
$("body").on('click', '[href*="#"]', function(e){
  var fixed_offset = 100;
  $('html,body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top - fixed_offset }, 1000);
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
#foods_section{
  margin-top:500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#foods_section">Foods</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Drinks</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="foods_section">Simple text</div>
```